# Setup ruby server for custom api

Tags: ruby

I am trying to implement an API that should run smoothly on a server created. [Here](http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/f7bde) is the code for the custom API (I didn't make it). The file name for that custom API is `pings.rb`. Then I created a `server.rb`, which looks like:

```
require 'sinatra'
get '/clear_data' do
  status 200
end
```

When I run `server.rb`, it successfully runs the server, but when I type `ruby pings.rb`, it returns some [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJmE6.png) in the API.

What would be a possible error in my server, which made the API not run smoothly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message says a post should return a code of 200 and it's not, however the route you've defined is a get request. Try:

```
post '/clear_data' do
  status 200
end
```

Comment: I already tried it but it return this kind of error https://i.imgur.com/Q4fi0p1.png

Comment: @ChristyRoyo: this now looks as a client problem (interpreting empty string as json). Server is working.

Comment: @ChristyRoyo: note that the error now comes from a different request/action.